# Trouble Transpiling startsWith() Using Babel and Rollup

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rollup

I'm having unexpected trouble transpiling ES2015's `startsWith` using Rollup and Babel. I'm using `babel-preset-env` and have the following in my `.babelrc`:

```
{
   "presets": [
     ["env", {
       "targets": {
         "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "not ie >= 10"]
       }, 
       "debug": true
     }]
   ]
 }
```

My `rollup.config.js` is set up to respect my `.babelrc`, and I'm seeing that it's correctly outputting in my debugging information that it's respecting my browser targets. Still, in my bundled JS, I'm seeing `startsWith` untouched, with no sight of a polyfill anywhere.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: check out [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel only transpiles syntax (like `let`/`const`, arrow functions, classes, etc.) and not API methods (like `.startsWith()` or `.includes()`).

For that, you'll need a polyfill, like [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/). However, if you only need the .startsWith function, [a simpler polyfill will suffice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill). That, or you could simply make your own `startsWith()` function and use that.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that stuff was out of Babel's scope. But should `babel-env-preset` automatically give me the polyfill I need, without having to include `babel-polyfill`? I thought I read things like that, anyway.

Comment: The env preset is _only_ responsible for syntax. They separate the polyfill out so you can include it in the most "comfortable" way, regardless of the build system you're using (e.g., if you wanted to use a script tag, or `require()`, or `import '...'`, etc.)

Comment: I think it used to work like that in babel 5, but 6 changed that. You generally want to do some feature detection before loading a polyfill that you might not need at all.

Comment: Awesome -- all good to know. Went with just writing my own little polyfill. Thanks! https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit/blob/master/src/startsWith.js